# How to retrieve data in front end from res.send and create page for each element in DB dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I've got a variable, say `data` containing data in the form of an `Array` with each item having a unique ID.

```
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send(data.map(data => "" + data.id + "")) //basically gets the data of the element in the Array whos Id has been given to the server. 
})
```

I have sent the data from the server to the front-end on a GET request. But how do I create a seperate webpage for **each element** dynamically in the data array? where do i have to write the html and the css?  I want a way with which I can create a page for each element like `domain.com/products/id` which displays information about the data entry which matches the Id . Do need to use pug? hbs?ejs? I' so confused.

Comment: [EJS](https://ejs.co) is a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript . [Check this out](https://learn.co/lessons/using-ejs-in-express#:~:text=To%20use%20EJS%20with%20Express,the%20location%20of%20your%20templates.) or official docs of EJS

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I found I had to use Javascript Templates to send data to a view. I used [ejs](https://ejs.co), which went pretty good!

Here's how it went:

**1.** fetch my data form my DB, which in this case is MongoDB using `db.findOne()`.

**2.** We get an array, let's say `data`.  send the variable to my view using the same `res.render` syntax, just in a cooler way.

```js
app.get('/blogs/:id',(req,res)=>{
     const data = //find function
     res.render('page.ejs', {body:data});
})
```

`:id` creates a page for every element in the DB.
and now the view that is, the public/page.ejs file has a global `body` variable, which
we can now use to show our blogs.

**3.** the front end markup in pages.ejs:

```
<div class="blogs">
<%=body.forEach (item)=>{%>
<p><%=item.blog%></p><br>
<%=}%>
</div>
```

We call a forEach function on the array, and create a paragraph element for each item in the array, that is for each blog.

Please not that `<%`, `<%=` and `%>` are EJS' tags. Read about them more in the [official docs](https://ejs.co).

Thanks [Mohammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12696223/mohammad-momeni) for letting me know about this. (From comments)